# How to capture onstop in marquee

Tags: html, jquery-plugins

I know that Chrome don't support onfinish event on marquee tag.
I decide to use JQuery plugin here: http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/
In this post, the author say it can capture stop event.
How ever, I cannot use it. Please help me out.

Comment: I found out the answer for this question. JQuery plugin is case-sensative.
So behavior='scroll' is ok, behavior=SCROLL is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

you should call .bind() for the the stop event. please see my example code below. hope it helps.

```
$(document).ready(
        function(){
        $('div.demo').marquee('pointer')
         .bind('stop', function() {alert($(this).text())})
         .mouseover(function () {
            $(this).trigger('stop');            
            //alert($(this).html());            
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).trigger('start');
        }).mousemove(function (event) {
            if ($(this).data('drag') == true) {
                this.scrollLeft = $(this).data('scrollX') + ($(this).data('x') - event.clientX);
            }
        }).mousedown(function (event) {
            $(this).data('drag', true).data('x', event.clientX).data('scrollX', this.scrollLeft);
        }).mouseup(function () {
            $(this).data('drag', false);
        })
    });
```